# How do I get keyboard input for a const* char parameter?

Tags: c++, char

I have an object that works with arrays of smaller objects. I am now creating a larger interface object that needs to collect input data and send it into a parameter of `const* char`. What code would I use to capture keyboard input of something like a 20 character title and be able to pass it into this parameter?

**In Short:**
How do you get keyboard input of a name and pass it into this:

```
void Insert(const char* t)
```

*I am restricted to using the iostream, iomanip, cstring, cctype libraries*

EDIT: You asked for the whole code, so here it is. All my input is having problems...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "store.h"

using namespace std;

void ShowMenu()
// Display the main program menu.
{
  cout << "\n\t\t*** BOOKSTORE MENU ***";
  cout << "\n\tA \tAdd a Book to Inventory";
  cout << "\n\tF \tFind a book from Inventory";
  cout << "\n\tS \tSell a book";
  cout << "\n\tD \tDisplay the inventory list";
  cout << "\n\tG \tGenre summary";
  cout << "\n\tO \tSort inventory list";
  cout << "\n\tM \tShow this Menu";
  cout << "\n\tX \teXit Program";
}

char GetAChar(const char* promptString)
// Prompt the user and get a single character,
// discarding the Return character.
// Used in GetCommand.
{
  char response;// the char to be returned

  cout << promptString;// Prompt the user
  cin >> response;// Get a char,
  response = toupper(response);// and convert it to uppercase
  cin.get();// Discard newline char from input.
  return response;
}

char Legal(char c)
// Determine if a particular character, c, corresponds
// to a legal menu command.  Returns 1 if legal, 0 if not.
// Used in GetCommand.
{
  return((c == 'A') || (c == 'F') || (c == 'S') || 
    (c == 'D') || (c == 'G') || (c == 'O') || 
    (c == 'M') || (c == 'X'));
}

char GetCommand()
// Prompts the user for a menu command until a legal 
// command character is entered.  Return the command character.
// Calls GetAChar, Legal, ShowMenu.
{
  char cmd = GetAChar("\n\n>");// Get a command character.

  while (!Legal(cmd))// As long as it's not a legal command,
  {// display menu and try again.
    cout << "\nIllegal command, please try again . . .";
    ShowMenu();
    cmd = GetAChar("\n\n>");
  }
  return cmd;
}

void Add(Store s)
{
  char* aTitle;
  char aAuthor[21];
  Genre aGenre = FICTION;
  double aPrice = 10.00;

  cout << "Enter title: ";
  cin >> aTitle;

  cout << "Enter author: ";
  cin.getline(aAuthor, 20);

  cout << aTitle << "  " << "aAuthor\n";

  s.Insert(aTitle, aAuthor, aGenre, aPrice);
}

void Find()
{
}

void Sell()
{
}

void Genre()
{
}

void Sort()
{
}

void Intro(Store s)
{
  double amount;

  cout << "*** Welcome to Bookstore Inventory Manager ***\n"
       << "Please input the starting money in the cash register: ";
  cin >> amount;

  s.SetCashRegister(amount);
}

int main()
{
  Store mainStore;// Create and initialize a Store.

  Intro(mainStore);//Display intro & set Cash Regsiter

  ShowMenu();// Display the menu.

  mainStore.Insert("A Clockwork Orange", "Anthony Burgess", SCIFI, 30.25);
  mainStore.Insert("X-Factor", "Anthony Burgess", SCIFI, 30.25);

  char command;// menu command entered by user
  do
  {
    command = GetCommand();// Retrieve a command.
    switch (command)
    {
    case 'A': Add(mainStore);           break;
    case 'F': Find();                   break;
    case 'S': Sell();                   break;
    case 'D': mainStore.DisplayStore(); break;
    case 'G': Genre();                  break;
    case 'O': Sort();                   break;
    case 'M': ShowMenu();               break;
    case 'X':                           break;
    }
  } while ((command != 'X'));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the beef (code)?

Comment: `collect input data and send it into a parameter of const char*` Can't be done (safely).  You can't (safely) modify the const char(s) that the pointer points at.

Comment: This is very basic stuff you're asking about. Just about any C++ textbook will show you to get input from the command prompt in the first chapter.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not against helping a beginner. I'm just advising you that your journey into C++ will go much smoother if you take the time to learn the basics from a C++ textbook, **then** come to stackoverflow for things that are unclear or more difficult. :-)

Comment: iostream, iomanip, cstring, and cctype are all part of the same library -- the C++ standard library. I.e., they are not separate libraries, merely separate headers. Also, if you have this completely-pointless restriction, does this mean that your question is for homework?

Comment: I appreciate it @EmileCormier! I promise I am consulting everything I possibly can right now. The textbook I am using doesn't do a great job explaining the finer points and I'm getting Abort Traps, Bus errors, and segmentation faults. I'm trying my hardest.

Comment: ildjarn, it almost certainly is homework. They want students to master working with pointers and manual memory management in the first few courses. It's like that at my local university.

Comment: @Emile : How uselessly backwards. In any case, the OP should have said so from the beginning.

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't use the string function. And I don't like to use others to help with homework, but errors were adding up and I was getting a bit tense. But, if homework help is not allowed, I'll chug through this alone I guess. Any pointers are welcomed.

Comment: jordan, homework help is allowed, but you should use the [homework] tag. Then, when you say things like "X and Y classes/functions are not allowed", we understand why. Also don't expect folks to give you the complete answer to the problem. They'll expect to see what you have done so far. They'll give you hints and tips. Here, you asked about one specific thing that was blocking you in your homework, and that's perfectly fine. :-)

Comment: Homework help is definitely allowed. We just want to help you in a pedagogically sound way. If this is homework, we try to lead you to the answer. If this is something else, we might just show you the answer.

Comment: jordan, another piece of advice is to learn how to use the debugger. It'll be the most time-saving thing you can possibly do. It'll allow you to step through your code line-by-line, and see what the current values of variables are. Even if you don't understand the meaning of an error, just knowing **where** it happens can help you fix it most of the time. It's also a good pedagogical tool, allowing you to see how algorithms work when stepping through your code.

Comment: @EmileCormier I completely understand, and thank you for your help thus far. I added the source code above if thats helps more. I feel as if this might be a more broad input error... not sure.

Also, I know how to debug. This is just odd. Its not my first go with C++, input is just tricky for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [`std::istream::getline(char *, std::streamsize)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/).

But, be sure that you pass it a valid pointer to allocated memory! That is, use it like this:

```
char buffer[80];
std::cin.getline(buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

and **not** like this:

```
char *p;
std::cin.getline(p, 80);  // Undefined behavior: using uninitialized variable
```

---

**EDIT**. You have this code:

```
char* aTitle;
...
cout << "Enter title: ";
cin >> aTitle;
```

This is a bug. You create a pointer called `aTitle`, and do not initialize it. That pointer now points at memory you do not own.

The `>>` operator writes data to the location pointed to by your pointer. Since your pointer does not point at anything you control, the `>>` will invoke undefined behavior when its writes through your pointer.

Lesson: make sure that you provide valid values for all of your pointers. (Broader lesson: never use pointers. (Okay, *almost never*.))

Immediately following, you have this code:

```
cout << "Enter author: ";
cin.getline(aAuthor, 20);
```

But, consider the input state. Your user just typed "Jaws", followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Your `cin>>aTitle` read "Jaws", and left "\n" in the input stream.

This `istream::getline` call reads up to the first newline, which is the newline that follows "Jaws"(!) and **not** the newline that follows "Peter Benchley"! So now, you have "Jaws" in aTitle (assuming you fix your previous bug), **nothing** in aAuthor, and "Peter Benchley\n" still in the input stream.

Lesson: Don't mix formatted input with `getline`. Use either one or the other consistently throughout your program.

Comment: The first error was just me experimenting with anything after becoming frustrated. It has since been fixed. So even with this error fixed, the aAuthor is still blank?

Comment: Both the Author and Title are using getline now (they were originally but as I said I was trying anything...)

Comment: You might check the validity of the input stream after each input operation: `if ( ! cin.getline(aAuthor, 20) ) { cout << "ERROR!\n"; }`

Comment: Also, your program will fail (it won't necessarily crash, just fail) if any input line is longer than expected. This includes the single-character input lines.

Comment: Okay I get this now: 
`menu.out(2770) malloc: *** error for object 0x10b4008c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6`

Answer (score 0):

Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to take a std::string input. And pass it to the function converting to a c-style string using member function c_str()

Comment: What about without use of the string library?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `std::string` and pass by reference.
2. You need a pointer to mutable data:

   char * t; // Pointer to mutable data

OR

```
char* const t; // Constant pointer to mutable character.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the weird restrictions (`iostream` is allowed, but not `std::string`), you might have a hard time finding your answer in a C++ text book. So here's some help:

```
char buffer[81];
std::cin >> buffer; // input some text (80 characters or less)

// A mutable character array can be implicitly converted
// to a const char* without casting.
Insert(buffer);
```

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! This allows a buffer-overflow attack. Entering a line longer than 80 chars will (at best) crash the program.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'd never use that in production code. This is just to help a beginner with his homework. I suppose it's never too early to learn about buffer overruns. :-)

Comment: If I change 81 to 8001, will that make it better? ;-P

Comment: I'm not a purist. It's okay (by me) to write that code, as long as the danger is highlighted.

Comment: The maximum the first field can be is 30. Can we throw out the rest after that?

Comment: A null character will be written just after the last character of the input text. This null character is what indicates the end of the string. The characters in the buffer following the null character will be random garbage. If your field will never be more than 30 characters, then you can use 31 as the size of the buffer (1 extra character reserved for null). Rob's way of inputting a string (`std::cin.getline(buffer, sizeof buffer);`) is safer than what I've shown above and will enforce the size restriction of the field.